# Apple 12W adapter for 4th generation iPad?

Tags: ipad

I bought a 4th generation iPad in 2013 and it is still serving me well. However, I recently broke the 12W power adapter that came with the iPad. I have looked for a replacement on the Apple website and have found a 12W adapter that looks the same as the one I received with my iPad. However, on the list of devices that are said to be compatible with this adapter, the 4th generation iPad does not appear. I was wondering if the adapter that Apple sells is still the same or if it is different now? If it is different, would I be able to use it with my iPad? I want to make sure to take these precautions so that I don’t damage the battery life on my device.

Comment: I tagged this as a dupe, even though the linked answer talks about USB-C - it actually applies to *all* chargers.  Basically, you can use any charger that's greater than or equal to what your device requires.  The device pulls (or *draws*) only what it needs.  The charger doesn't "push" anything to the device.  Because of this, you can't damage your battery.

Comment: Also, get a *quality* charger.  You don't have to buy Apple, but don't get a no-name brand either.  I use [Anker chargers](https://amzn.to/2SallZK) almost exclusively and recommend them highly.  I also get quality lightning cables from them and not the cheap ones found everywhere.  Yes, they cost a few $$ more, but I'm not risking my expensive device just to save a few pennies.